# Regex compilation in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am trying to do:

```
uri=uri.replaceFirst("{}",param.toString());
```

I'm supposed to use regex in place of `{}` but that should not be a compilation problem because method signature takes String and `{}` is a perfectly valid string. Below is `replaceFirst()`:

```
public String replaceFirst(String regex, String replacement)
```

Help me understand how is this a compilation error.

IntellijIDEA 2018.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first parameter is expected to be a valid regex. Because there are metacharacters, you must escape:

```
uri=uri.replaceFirst("\\{\\}",param.toString());
```

[IntelliJ does inspection](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/suppressing-inspections.html) that allows it to report such errors. This is an IDE feature. Compiling this code with `javac` wouldn't cause it to fail.

You can disable inspection (alt+enter, details on the page linked to above):

[image]

Comment: I get it, I need to use valid regex string but that should not be a compliation problem.

Comment: Your Java code compiles, but it's the compilation of the REGEX that failed. The exception raised by Java is `java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException thrown: Illegal repetition`, which is not a compilation problem. The terminology may be subtle, but sometimes we simply say "regex compilation". You get the idea.

Comment: I understand it sounds strange but it's a compliation error. Try with intellij

Comment: @SachinVerma Edited with information about IntelliJ's inspection feature that does this type of validation

Answer (score 3):

`{}` is a special regex character which represents the range operator so you have to escape it before using it

```
// normal use
    "".replaceFirst("a{1,2}","");
```

As shown, `{}` is recognised as range to match minimum and maximum occurrences of `a`

so while using regex you have to provide some character/word along with minimum and maximum value with range operator `{}`(otherwise it can cause regex engine to crash or behave unexpectedly so compiler is being proactive here)

solution : escape it using `\\`

```
uri = uri.replaceFirst("\\{\\}",param.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

This is NOT a compilation error that you receive. It's an inspection from IntelliJ, even though it's underlined in red.

[image]

You may disable the inspection by going into your settings

[image]